# Can someone help me describe this typescript?

Tags: typescript

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(i);
  }, 100 * i);
}
```

When you run it:
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
But I cannot understand how it is working like we are multiplying i with 100??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: `100 * i` is the *timeout` after which a message would show up.

Answer (score 1):

The `setTimeout()` method calls a function or evaluates an expression after a specified number of milliseconds.

so for the first loop, you have a delay of `i*100=0`, then the delay became `100` then `200` and so on, so the code logs `i` every time, but with different delays.

Answer (score 0):

`i` is going from `0` to `9`, and in each iteration, it sets a timeout to `i` times 100.

That is, you end up with ten timeouts set for `0ms` (`0 * 100`), `100ms` (`1 * 100`), `200ms` (`2 * 100`), and so on until `900ms` (`9 * 100`).

```
i | i * 100 | delay
--+---------+------
0 | 0 * 100 |   0ms
1 | 1 * 100 | 100ms
2 | 2 * 100 | 200ms
3 | 3 * 100 | 300ms
4 | 4 * 100 | 400ms
5 | 5 * 100 | 500ms
6 | 6 * 100 | 600ms
7 | 7 * 100 | 700ms
8 | 8 * 100 | 800ms
9 | 9 * 100 | 900ms
```

Answer (score 0):

The For loop is calling the setTimeout() function total 10 times

So if simplified it can be written as follows...

```
setTimeout(function() { console.log(0); }, 0); # when i=0

setTimeout(function() { console.log(1); }, 100); # when i=1

setTimeout(function() { console.log(2); }, 200); # when i=2

setTimeout(function() { console.log(3); }, 300); # when i=3

and so on...
```

So whats happening is for each number in range of 0 to 9, `setTimeout` function sets the `console.log()` method for every interval of 100 ms. Try replacing that 100 to 1000 and you will see that the numbers are printed in a one second delay.

If you remove the i multiplied with 100 and just keep a specific value (like only 100) it will seem like all the numbers are printed at the same time after that value of interval.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Help guys I am a newbie so I was not understanding it right

```
settimeout(function, parameter)

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(i);
    }, 100 * i);
  }
```

when we are executing it the value of i doesn't change after multiplying by hundred but just gives a 100ms delay in the output and every it increases by 100ms.
And at the end the delay is 900ms.